# Embed Message: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message v.13 (discord.js)

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to send an embed message that I wrote before the embed was sent. Unfortunately this doesn't work. The message that I type is getting deleted but the embed is not sent and I get an error code.

Thats my Script:

```js
        case 'a':
        case 'A':

        let part = message.content.split(" ");
        if(!message.member.permissions.has(Discord.Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_ROLES)) return;
        if(!part[1]) return;
        var text = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
        message.delete();

        const aembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('RED')
        .setThumbnail('png')
        .addField('Our newest announcement: ', text, true)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter('This is an announcement' + 'from' + message.member.displayName + '!')

        message.channel.send({embed: aembed})
```

My error code is:

```
C:\User\Bot v13\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Alle Discord Bots\Bot v13\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Alle Discord Bots\Bot v13\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async TextChannel.send (C:\Alle Discord Bots\Bot v13\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:172:15) {       
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/897416583549427743/messages',
  code: 50006,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discord.js v13 no longer uses the `embed` property. Use the `embeds` property instead (it’s an array!)

```js
message.channel.send({embeds: [aembed]})
```