# A Discord Bot Embed Error: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Tags: discord.js, bots

I've tried writing a discord bot, nearly finished it but this error just appeared and I don't know what's wrong with the code.

The Error:

> DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
> at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
> at async TextChannel.send (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:176:15) {
> method: 'post',
> path: '/channels/991019562625552466/messages',
> code: 50006,
> httpStatus: 400,
> requestData: {
> json: {
> content: undefined,
> tts: false,
> nonce: undefined,
> embeds: undefined,
> components: undefined,
> username: undefined,
> avatar_url: undefined,
> allowed_mentions: undefined,
> flags: undefined,
> message_reference: undefined,
> attachments: undefined,
> sticker_ids: undefined
> },
> files: []
> }
> }

The code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'command',
    description: "Embeds!",
    execute(message, args, Discord) {
        const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#FF0000')
        .setTitle('This is a title.')
        .setURL('https://www.youtube.com')
        .setDescription('This is an embed.')
        .addFields(
            {name: 'Field 1', value: 'Text 1'},
            {name: 'Field 2', value: 'Text 2'},
            {name: 'Field 3', value: 'Text 3'}
        )
        .setImage('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg')
        
        message.channel.send(newEmbed);
    }
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed Message: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message v.13 (discord.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539920/embed-message-discordapierror-cannot-send-an-empty-message-v-13-discord-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of discord.js v13 embeds are sent via the `MessageOptions` object passed to the send method.

Updated code would be:

```js
message.channel.send({embeds: [newEmbed]});
```

Documentation:
[BaseGuildTextChannel#send](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/BaseGuildTextChannel?scrollTo=send) takes
<[MessageOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions)> extends <[BaseMessageOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/BaseMessageOptions)>